# Is there a way to create a "personalized" form/template in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, forms

Is there any way to create a "personalized" template in Outlook 2007?

In Microsoft Word, you can specify form fields via Mail Merge, so you can start a letter like "Hello «FirstName»", and it will populate the «FirstName» field with data from the recipients list.  Is there a way to do something similar with Outlook templates and the Global Address List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail merge feature of Microsoft Word supports sending e-mail and using Outlook as a source for contact information.  Simply use mail merge as you would normally but instead select "e-mail" instead of "letter" as the output format, and choose "Outlook contacts" as your recipient source.

For more information, refer to [this support article from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-outlook-contacts-as-a-data-source-for-a-mail-merge-HP010099500.aspx).